# Migrating from BizTalk 2010 to BizTalk 2020

Tags: migration, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2020

We are currently running a simplistic installation of BizTalk 2010 for some EDI mapping.  I'd like to migrate these applications to BizTalk 2020.  I'm not concerned about keeping the history of previous transactions.

Is it as simple as setting up a new BizTalk 2020 installation and importing the applications\Parties to 2020, or do they need to make a hop through another version (ie 2016)?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean just to export the MSI and parties and then re-import them into BizTalk 2020, then the answer is probably no.

If you mean to open each solution in Visual Studio 2019 and upgrade them, recompile and deploy, and then test for issues, then yes, that is achievable.

Note: Going from BizTalk 2010 to a higher version there is a known issue with maps where the later versions use XslCompiledTransform class instead of XslTransform.  See [Known issues in BizTalk Server 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/biztalk/known-issues-biztalk-server-2013).  I also wrote a blog about it [BizTalk 2013 R2 CU2 & BizTalk 2016 – Use XSL Transform](https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2016/02/27/biztalk-2013-r2-cu2-use-xsl-transform/) and why you should fix the maps, rather than try and default it back to XslTransform.

EDI might have problems, because sometime parties cannot be directly migrated. In which case you will need to use the BizTalk Server Party Migration Tool which usually is included.

Also the SQL adapter has been removed in BizTalk 2020 (see [Deprecated & Removed List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/whats-new-in-biztalk-server-2020#deprecated--removed-list)), so if you have any ports using that you will need to replace it with WCF-SQL

Comment: Thank you!!  I think that's what I was looking for...  I'll research the XSLTransform and come back with results.  Appreciate your time answering here.